# KOMA Script: How to exactly reconstruct paragraph settings for parskip=full by using \setparsizes

Tags: spacing, formatting, koma-script, line-spacing

How can I **exactly** reconstruct KOMA Script's paragraph settings for `parskip=full` in

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrbook}
```

by using

```
\setparsizes{indent}{distance}{last-line end space}
```

?

I have tried `\setparsizes{0.0em}{1.0\baselineskip plus 1.0\baselineskip}{1.0em plus 1.0fil}` but unfortunately, it's not exactly the same.

Maybe someone can find out the internals of how it works.

Comment: it is  `plus 0.1\baselineskip`  not `plus 1.0\baselineskip`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please create the according answer, so that I can accept it? Furthermore, I have just created a follow-up question based on this question (mainly for verification purposes), maybe you could have a look at it as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522763/koma-script-how-to-exactly-reconstruct-paragraph-settings-for-parskip-and-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out, `\setparsizes{0.0em}{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip}{1.0em plus 1.0fil}` exactly reconstructs KOMA Script's paragraph settings for `parskip=full`, so that both pfd files are typeset completely equal.