# KOMA Script: How to exactly reconstruct paragraph settings for parskip=... and others by using \setparsizes

Tags: spacing, formatting, koma-script, line-spacing

**1.) Verification:**

Is it correct to **exactly** reconstruct KOMA Script's paragraph settings for `parskip=no` in

```
\documentclass[parskip=no]{scrbook}
```

by using

```
\setparsizes{1.0em}{0.0pt plus 1.0pt}{0.0pt plus 1.0fil}
```

? I cannot detect any differences in the created pdf files.

---

**2.) Verification:**

Is it correct to **exactly** reconstruct KOMA Script's paragraph settings for `parskip=half` in

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}
```

by using

```
\setparsizes{0.0em}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}{1.0em plus 1.0fil}
```

? I cannot detect any differences in the created pdf files.

---

**3.) Derivation:**

Furthermore, *would* it be correct to **exactly** derive new KOMA Script paragraph settings according to the non-existing setting `parskip=quarter` (which should mean quarter a line vertical space between paragraphs) in

```
\documentclass[parskip=quarter]{scrbook}
```

by using

```
\setparsizes{0.0em}{0.25\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip}{1.0em plus 1.0fil}
```

, according to its definition

```
\setparsizes{indent}{distance}{last-line end space}
```

, or should some values (especially the `distance` value) be adjusted differently? Is there a certain rule to follow for typesetting the `distance` value, when scaling the used `distance` factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values can be found in the cls and are (shortened) this here:
`\z@` translates to 0pt and @plus to plus.

```
     {never}{0},%
      {false}{1},{off}{1},{no}{1},%
      {full-}{2},%
      {half-}{3},%
      {full}{4},{true}{4},{on}{4},{yes}{4},%
      {half}{5},%
      {full+}{6},%
      {half+}{7},%
      {full*}{8},%
      {half*}{9},%
      {relative}{10},%
      {absolute}{11}%
      %0
        \setparsizes{1em}{\z@}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
      % 1
        \setparsizes{1em}{\z@ \@plus \p@}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
      % 2
        \setparsizes{\z@}{1\baselineskip \@plus .1\baselineskip}{%
          \z@ \@plus 1fil}%
      % 3
        \setparsizes{\z@}{.5\baselineskip \@plus .5\baselineskip}{%
          \z@ \@plus 1fil}%
      % 4
        \setparsizes{\z@}{1\baselineskip \@plus .1\baselineskip}{%
          1em \@plus 1fil}%
      % 5
        \setparsizes{\z@}{.5\baselineskip \@plus .5\baselineskip}{%
          1em \@plus 1fil}%
      % 6
        \setparsizes{\z@}{1\baselineskip \@plus .1\baselineskip}{%
          .3333\linewidth\@plus 1fil}%
      % 7
        \setparsizes{\z@}{.5\baselineskip \@plus .5\baselineskip}{%
          .3333\linewidth \@plus 1fil}%
      % 8
        \setparsizes{\z@}{1\baselineskip \@plus .1\baselineskip}{%
          .25\linewidth \@plus 1fil}%
      % 9
        \setparsizes{\z@}{.5\baselineskip \@plus .5\baselineskip}{%
          .25\linewidth \@plus 1fil}%
```

Comment: This is amazing! Supposing `\p@` translates to `1pt`, 1.) and 2.) are verified successfully.